# Piping command output to tee but also save exit code of command

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, sh, tee

I have a shell script in which I wrap a command (mvn clean install), to redirect the output  to a logfile.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
mvn clean install $@ | tee $logfile
echo $? # Does not show the return code of mvn clean install
```

Now if `mvn clean install` fails with an error, I want my wrapper shell script also fail with that error. But since I'm piping all the output to tee, I cannot access the return code of `mvn clean install`, so when I access `$?` afterwards, it's always 0 (since tee successes).

I tried letting the command write the error output to a separate file and checking that afterwards, but the error output of mvn is always empty (seems like it only writes to stdout).

How can I preserve the return code of `mvn clean install` but still piping the output to a logfile?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Since you're running `bash`, you can use its [$PIPESTATUS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIPESTATUSREF) variable instead of `$?`:

```
mvn clean install $@ | tee $logfile
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Comment: As mentioned below if you have more than a single pipe then you'll need to check the status of each command to know where it failed.

Comment: Also very important: the variable is ephemeral, so even "echo"-ing it out will lose you the value from running the pipeline. Assign it to another variable unless you will access it immediately, and only once.

Answer (score 389):

You can set the `pipefail` [shell option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) option on to get the behavior you want.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command
>   in the pipeline, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled (see [The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)).
>   If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the
>   value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status,
>   or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Example:

```
$ false | tee /dev/null ; echo $?
0
$ set -o pipefail
$ false | tee /dev/null ; echo $?
1
```

To restore the original pipe setting:

```
$ set +o pipefail
```

Comment: This seems a more elegant solution than the accepted solution

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer requires you to know in advance which command in your pipes will fail. If you are piping 5 different commands together, you will have to guess which one in the array will fail.

Comment: Or do a loop over PIPESTATUS

Comment: to restore the original pipe setting: `$ set +o pipefail`

Comment: Note, `pipefail` is also supported by `dash` on ubuntu

Comment: Great answer, however I would point out, that `set +o pipfail` will turn OFF the pipefail (not return it to its original state) as the docs say `Using ‘+’ rather than ‘-’ causes these options to be turned **off**. The options can also be used upon invocation of the shell. The current set of options may be found in $-.`

Comment: Also if you're going for a one-liner: `bash -c "set -o pipefail && false | tee log.txt"` will exit with an error code.  Very useful for something like a build process that you're logging.

Comment: if `tee` is killed, it doesn't return...

Comment: imho this should be the correct answer: `(set -o pipefail && false | tee log.txt)` execute the stuff in a sub-shell so that the original state of the pipefail flag will be restored

Comment: what is the scope of `pipefail` if not run in a subshell as @JiriKremser suggests?  I.e. if the script fails before `set +o pipefail` is called, will `pipefail` still be enabled when other scripts are called?

Answer (score 19):

You could run the mvn command and cache the exit code... I use the "false" command for my example.

```
$ { false ; echo $? > /tmp/false.status ; } | tee $logfile
$ cat /tmp/false.status
1
```

That way you can use the status file content to make further decisions.

I'm curious now whether there is a more eloquent way to accomplish this.

Comment: I hope the final answer isn't shell specific (ie: bash only).

Comment: Perfect! I prefer this one to not rely only on bash :-) Thanks @Demosthenex

Comment: But I used ( )  instead of { } to capture output ....

Answer (score 4):

Workaround (note: a perfer @Frederic's solution):

```
f=`mktemp`
(mvn clean install $@; echo $?>$f) | tee $logfile
e=`cat $f` #error in variable e
rm $f
```

Comment: Could we save a fork with `read e < $f` instead of the `cat`?

Comment: sure. and you probably want to create a tempfile to avoid race conditions. but, as you can see there are better solutions...