# Capture the output of Perl's 'system()'

Tags: perl, shell

I need to run a shell command with system() in Perl. For example,

```
system('ls')
```

The system call will print to [STDOUT](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#standard-output), but I want to capture the output into a variable so that I can do future processing with my Perl code.

Comment: Don't use system, use open() with a pipe.

Comment: See also [What's the difference between Perl's backticks, system, and exec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

Comment: None of the answers here covers the `qx//` operator. [An answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec/800105#800105) does.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That's what backticks are for. From [`perldoc perlfaq8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can%27t-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system%28%29%3f):

> **Why can't I get the output of a command with `system()`?**
>
> You're confusing the purpose of [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and backticks (``). `system()`
>   runs a command and returns exit status information (as a 16 bit value:
>   the low 7 bits are the signal the process died from, if any, and the
>   high 8 bits are the actual exit value). Backticks (``) run a command
>   and return what it sent to STDOUT.
>
> ```
> my $exit_status   = system("mail-users");
> my $output_string = `ls`;
> ```

See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) for more details.

Comment: Actually I think it's valid to ask the question: `system()` has advantages when passing parameters as an array (in case of "unsafe" parameters) that none of the alternatives have (AFAIK).

Answer (score 23):

[`IPC::Run`](http://www.metacpan.org/module/IPC::Run) is my favourite module for this kind of task. Very powerful and flexible, and also trivially simple for small cases.

```
use IPC::Run 'run';

run [ "command", "arguments", "here" ], ">", \my $stdout;

# Now $stdout contains output
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply use similar to the Bash example:

```
    $variable=`some_command some args`;
```

That's all. Notice, you will not see any printings to STDOUT on the output because this is redirected to a variable.

This example is unusable for a command that interact with the user, except when you have prepared answers. For that, you can use something like this using a stack of shell commands:

```
    $variable=`cat answers.txt|some_command some args`;
```

Inside the *answers.txt* file you should prepare all answers for some_command to work properly.

I know this isn't the best way for programming :) But this is the simplest way how to achieve the goal, specially for Bash programmers.

Of course, if the output is bigger (`ls` with subdirectory), you shouldn't get all output at once. Read the command by the same way as you read a regular file:

```
open CMD,'-|','your_command some args' or die $@;
my $line;
while (defined($line=<CMD>)) {
    print $line; # Or push @table,$line or do whatever what you want processing line by line
}
close CMD;
```

An additional extended solution for processing a long command output without extra Bash calling:

```
my @CommandCall=qw(find / -type d); # Some example single command
my $commandSTDOUT; # File handler
my $pid=open($commandSTDOUT),'-|'); # There will be an implicit fork!
if ($pid) {
    #parent side
    my $singleLine;
    while(defined($singleline=<$commandSTDOUT>)) {
        chomp $line; # Typically we don't need EOL
        do_some_processing_with($line);
    };
    close $commandSTDOUT; # In this place $? will be set for capture
    $exitcode=$? >> 8;
    do_something_with_exit_code($exitcode);
} else {
    # Child side, there you really calls a command
    open STDERR, '>>&', 'STDOUT'; # Redirect stderr to stdout if needed. It works only for child - remember about fork
    exec(@CommandCall); # At this point the child code is overloaded by an external command with parameters
    die "Cannot call @CommandCall"; # Error procedure if the call will fail
}
```

If you use a procedure like that, you will capture all procedure output, and you can do everything processing line by line. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to run system() instead of backticks because I wanted to see the output of `rsync --progress`. However, I also wanted to capture the output in case something goes wrong depending on the return value. (This is for a backup script). This is what I am using now:

```
use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
use Term::ANSIColor qw(colored colorstrip);

sub mysystem {
    my $cmd = shift; # "rsync -avz --progress -h $fullfile $copyfile";
    my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile();
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/6872163/2923406
    # I want to have rsync progress output on the terminal AND capture it in case of error.
    # Need to use pipefail because 'tee' would be the last cmd otherwise and hence $? would be wrong.
    my @cmd = ("bash", "-c", "set -o pipefail && $cmd 2>&1 | tee $filename");
    my $ret = system(@cmd);
    my $outerr = join('', <$fh>);
    if ($ret != 0) {
        logit(colored("ERROR: Could not execute command: $cmd", "red"));
        logit(colored("ERROR: stdout+stderr = $outerr", "red"));
        logit(colored("ERROR: \$? = $?, \$! = $!", "red"));
    }
    close $fh;
    unlink($filename);
    return $ret;
}

# And logit() is something like:
sub logit {
    my $s = shift;
    my ($logsec, $logmin, $loghour, $logmday, $logmon, $logyear, $logwday, $logyday, $logisdst) = localtime(time);
    $logyear += 1900;
    my $logtimestamp = sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $logyear, $logmon+1, $logmday, $loghour, $logmin, $logsec);
    my $msg = "$logtimestamp $s\n";
    print $msg;
    open LOG, ">>$LOGFILE";
    print LOG colorstrip($msg);
    close LOG;
}
```

Comment: why you call system("rm $filename") ?   you have internal procedure unlink $filename , it do the same without extra calling sh or bash interpreter.

Comment: @Znik: Also `system("rm $filename")` can cause serious problems if `$filename` contains shell metacharacdters or starts with `-`. `unlink $filename` directly removes the named file.