# How to pass null arguments to perl script called from main perl script [backtics]

Tags: perl, unix

I want to call a **perl script(B.pl)** which will list the files available in the remote server from the main **perl script(A.pl)** by passing more than one optional arguments.

Since the arguments were optional, if I use backticks the arguments are getting assigned to wrong variables in B.pl.

If I use `@list=system(B.pl, argv0, argv1, argv2);` then though some arguments are undef it is getting correctly assigned in B.pl but the STDOUT is not getting assigned to @list in the calling script.

I am new to perl, please guide in this scenario. Is there any way to pass null arguments with backticks ?

In A.pl:

```
my @filelist = system( B.pl, $argv0, $argv1, $argv2, $argv3);
my @filelist1 = `B.pl $argv0 $argv1 $argv2 $argv3`;
```

In B.pl:

```
my $loc   = uc( $ARGV[0] );
my $msk   = uc( $ARGV[1] );
my $usr   = $ARGV[2];
my $usr1  = $ARGV[3];
```

Comment: `system` returns the callee's exit value, not what it printed.

Comment: Please show how you are invoking `B.pl` and how you are assigning the arguments it receives.

Comment: You should consider using the `--name val` notation for optional arguments, and use Getopt::Long to parse the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use "zero length strings" (`""` or `''`) as parameters inside back-ticks:

```
perl -e "print `perl -e 'print $ARGV[2]' 0 '' 2`"
```

**OR** use perl module for handling command line options e.g. Getopt::Std

Comment: Oh, hey, that totally works.  Nevermind, this is way better than my answer.

Comment: @darch, I disagree. Using switches is far better for optional args

Comment: @darch IMHO Command line switches are better option for non tiny and non short maintenance span scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question about Perl so much as it is about the shell.  You are trying to pass a bunch of parameters, some of which are optional.  Fortunately, this is a well-understood problem.  The answer is to pass named options instead of positional arguments.  The standard way to do that in Perl is with [`Getopt::Long`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long).

For example, in `B.pl`, you could say

```
use Getopt::Long;
my ($loc, $msk, $usr, $usr1);
GetOptions(
    "loc=s"     => \$loc,
    "msk=s"     => \$msk,
    "usr=s"     => \$usr,
    "usr1=s"    => \$usr1,
) or die "Something wrong with your options!";
```

And the invocation in `A.pl` would read:

```
my @filelist1 = `B.pl '--loc=$argv0' '--msk=$argv1' '--usr=$argv2' '--usr1=$argv3'`;
```

There are more sophisticated approaches.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521312/9719), for example, we find out about [`IPC::Run`](http://www.metacpan.org/module/IPC%3A%3ARun).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a safe version of the backticks operator or of `readpipe` doesn't exist. It has been on the `perl` TODO list for years!

But you can do it yourself easily using `open`:

```
open my $handle, '-|', 'B.pl', $argv0, $argv1, $argv2, $argv3
    or die "unable to run external command: $!";
my $output = do { local $/; <$handle> };
close $handle
    or die "unable to capture output from child command: $!";
$? and die "remote command exited with non zero return code: $?";
```