# CGI Printing issue

Tags: perl, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:all);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use strict; 
print "Content-type: text/plain\n";
print "\n";

my $date = system('date');

print "Date :: $date";
```

The above code keeps producing the output of `Date :: 0` instead of the current date.
I can't find any solution for this problem. Please help.

Comment: `system` returns the status code of the executed command, not the output. You could use the backticks instead.

Comment: or better you should use a perl function to get the date

Comment: And the title is misleading. This ist not a problem with CGI, it is a problem capturing the output of an external command.

Comment: Can you teach me how to use the backticks please. @dgw

Comment: Searching within SO should give you enough input ... for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968/whats-the-difference-between-perls-backticks-system-and-exec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `system` command, use `backtick`. `system` command doesn't return value in a variable. Change this line:

```
my $date = system('date');
```

to

```
my $date = `date`;
```

See this for more understanding about `system` and `backtick`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/800105/4248931

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the [system command](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) is the return value of the call. For a successful call this will be 0. If you want to capture the output of a command use backticks or IPC. Look at this answer: [Capture the output of Perl system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514947/capture-the-output-of-perl-system)

```perl
my $date = `date`;

print "Date :: $date";
```

But better would be to use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.21/lib/DateTime.pm).

Comment: DateTime is not in the Perl core. To get a textual representation of the date, it's enough to simply call `localtime`.