# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 11 (BuildPhase Script)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, shell, sh

I have created a custom **universal** framework and I need to add this scripted to its build phases so that the Universal framework will remove unused architectures. Which is necessary if I ever plan on using for the app store in an app.

But I am getting compile error (Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code):
[image]

[image]

**Script:**

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
FRAMEWORK="TestFramework"
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/$FRAMEWORK.framework/$FRAMEWORK"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()
for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRAFRAMEWORK="TestFramework"
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/$FRAMEWORK.framework/$FRAMEWORK"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()
for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"CTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
```

**This is from a tutorial here:** [Writing Custom Universal Framework in Xcode 10.2 and iOS 12](https://medium.com/allatoneplace/writing-custom-universal-framework-in-xcode-9-and-ios-11-7a63a2ce024a)

*The problem could be as simply a improperly written string or a space where it shouldn't be, but I don't know.*

**Findings: I know it has something to do with either the for loop or something inside of it because when I delete the for loop and it's contents/nest-code that error goes away.**

**Reproduce: to reproduce the error you can simply make a dummy Xcode project and then Select the Project tab called → yourProject.xcodeproj, Choose Target → Project Name → Select Build Phases → Press “+” → New Run Script Phase → Name the Script as “Remove Unused Architectures Script” → and finally just copy and past the code.**

Comment: any findings?? i have same issue

Answer (score 1):

The for loops may be to blame here. They could capture any exit codes that happen. I experienced a similar issue on this.

- change your for loops,

  - switch to a while loop using `<<<` action: :https://stackoverflow.com/a/16854326/4970749
  - or keep for loop see answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197183
- Make sure you aren't getting an exit code, and if you are pass it to an outer variable. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871917/4970749