# Duplicate stdout to stderr and vice-versa at the same time

Tags: bash

I am currently using a distant script that I cannot modify, which displays the results of a bash command, but:

- I cannot change the distant script nor the bash command, but I can the command's outputs
- The script shows only stdout if the command has no exit code
- The script shows only stderr if the command has an exit code

This is hard for observability, as some important context is sometimes outputted to stdout even if the command fails, and on the other hand some part of the code failing can lead to data being outputted to stderr even though I get the expected result without error.

I thought I would easily find a solution on this site, but I cannot find it anywhere:

Is there a way to redirect the output so that BOTH the original messages from stderr and stdout are meged and outputted to BOTH stderr and stdout ?

Comment: Do you mean something that has the same effect as `command 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; echo "$line" >&2; done` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
distant 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr
```

do what you want?

Comment: Note that this doesn't preserve the exit status of `distant` -- you'd have to add something like `; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to the end (and make sure it executes in bash, not some other shell).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, good point.  There are a few ways to capture the exit status of `distant`.  See [Piping command output to tee but also save exit code of command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6871859/4154375) and [Pipe output and capture exit status in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221833/4154375).  Be *very* wary of using `set -o pipefail` though.  (See [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).)